# Difference betwen today's date and date from database

Tags: android, sqlite

I would like to calculate the difference between today's date and the date of the database.I wrote a method, but it does not work completely. How should I draw a difference of days between two dates?

```
   public ArrayList<String> roznicadni(){
    ArrayList<String> roznicadni = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = DbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    final String date = sdf.format(new Date());
    String zapytanie = "SELECT "+date+" - "+Zlecenia_stale.Kolumny.datatstale+" AS xxx FROM "+Zlecenia_stale.NAZWA_TABELI+" WHERE id_portfela = "+WyborPortfela.portfel_id;
    Cursor kursor = db.rawQuery(zapytanie, null);
    for (kursor.moveToFirst(); !kursor.isAfterLast(); kursor.moveToNext()) {
        roznicadni.add(1,kursor.getString(kursor.getColumnIndex("xxx")));
    }
    return roznicadni;
}
```

Comment: why don't you save the date in long(millisecond) format in the database, convert today's date in millisecond and then find the difference and convert them to days,months,hours, minutes or whatever you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use `TimeUnit`

```
long dif  = currentDate.getTime() - dbDate.getTime();

long diffInSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(dif);
long diffInMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(dif);
long diffInHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(dif);
```

Comment: The database holding the date as a String. I think it's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String database_date = "2016-01-08 12:56:50";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

try {

    Date oldDate = dateFormat.parse(database_date);
    System.out.println(oldDate);

    Date currentDate = new Date();

    //difference in days,hours,minutes etc..
    long diff = currentDate.getTime() - oldDate.getTime();
    long seconds = diff / 1000;
    long minutes = seconds / 60;
    long hours = minutes / 60;
    long days = hours / 24;

    if (oldDate.before(currentDate)) {

        Log.e("oldDate", "is previous date");
        Log.e("Difference: ", " seconds: " + seconds + " minutes: " + minutes
                + " hours: " + hours + " days: " + days);

    }


} catch (ParseException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```